# Is it possible to rename png files by the time of creation, not after

Tags: pdf, tesseract, tess4j

I am using  File[] imageFile = PdfUtilities.convertPdf2Png(new File("MYPATH")) command to generate png from pdf , which is giving file name as "workingimage01","workingimage02"...."workingimage0n" and so on, is it possible to change this name setting by the time png's are generated. Thanks in advance.
I am trying this command for 10 pdf parallel, so it is overlapping. thats why i need to know is there a way or i am asking out of the box question.

Answer (score 0):

The name is hard coded in the [source](https://github.com/nguyenq/tess4j/blob/master/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/tess4j/util/PdfUtilities.java). You can create an overloaded method that takes another parameter for the working files' name.

Comment: Thanks a lot, can you share source as i am unable to find

Comment: Click on the `source` link above.

Comment: i got but i am unable to open , can you please give me the method name which i need to override , i have classes so i can do that a bit faster. Thanks in advance